# How to delete everything after the cursor?

Tags: bash, terminal, tput

I want to delete everything after the cursor; not just the current line, but every remaining characters after the current position.

For example of `tput sc; ll; tput rc`:

```
root@test:~# tput sc; ll; tput rc
root@test:~# {CURRENT_CURSOR_POSITION}
drwx------  5 root root  4096 Feb 23 16:34 ./
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root  4096 Jul  1  2021 ../
-rw-------  1 root root    59 Feb 23 16:34 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3106 Dec  5  2019 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb  8 17:07 .local/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   161 Dec  5  2019 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun 21  2021 snap/
drwx------  2 root root  4096 Feb 22 11:56 .ssh/
-rw-------  1 root root 12976 Feb  8 17:07 .viminfo
```

This will leave the cursor at the second line, with the output of `ll` remaining.

I'm looking for a way to either

1. delete each line using `tput el` until it reaches the saved position, so the chain of command would be: `tput sc; ll; while_deleting; tput rc`. This may invoke `tput el` for everyline which seems like redundant but should be alright.
2. delete everything *after* going back to the saved position.

I've looked into many answers such as [how to delete all characters after cursor in shell](https://superuser.com/questions/362113/how-to-delete-all-characters-after-cursor-in-shell), [Bash: delete from cursor till end of line with a keyboard shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269046/bash-delete-from-cursor-till-end-of-line-with-a-keyboard-shortcut), and so on, but all the answers focus on deleting the current line, not the rest.

Comment: @KarlT Yes did it! Can you post an answer so I would accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tput cd`

> `cd`      Clear to end of display (*)

https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termutils-2.0/html_chapter/tput_1.html#SEC8